# Prevent gcc from mangling my AVX2 intrinsics copy into REP MOVS

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-optimization, intrinsics, avx2

Consider the following loop:

```
template <typename T>
void copytail(T* __restrict__ dest, const T* __restrict__ src, size_t count) {
  constexpr size_t chunk_size = 4 * 32;
  size_t byte_count = sizeof(T) * count;
  size_t chunks = byte_count / chunk_size;
  auto rest = byte_count - byte_count / chunk_size * chunk_size;
  auto rest_vecs = (rest + 31) / 32;
  __m256i* dest256 = (__m256i*)((char *)dest + byte_count - rest_vecs * 32);
  __m256i* src256  = (__m256i*)((char *)src  + byte_count - rest_vecs * 32);
  for (size_t j = 0; j < rest_vecs; j++) {
      _mm256_storeu_si256(dest256 + j, _mm256_loadu_si256(src256 + j));
  }
}


void tail_copy(char* d, const char* s, size_t overshoot) {
    copytail(d, s, overshoot);
}
```

Don't think too hard about what it does, as it is a reduced test case based on a more complete function - but basically it copies up to 4 AVX2 vectors from `src` to `dest`, aligned to the *end* of the regions.

For whatever reason<sup>1</sup>, gcc 8.1 at `-O3` produces this odd assembly:

```
tail_copy(char*, char const*, unsigned long):
  mov rax, rdx
  and eax, 127
  add rax, 31
  mov rcx, rax
  and rcx, -32
  sub rdx, rcx
  shr rax, 5
  je .L30
  sal rax, 5
  mov r8d, eax
  add rdi, rdx
  add rsi, rdx
  test dil, 1
  jne .L32
.L3:
  test dil, 2
  jne .L33
.L4:
  test dil, 4
  jne .L34
.L5:
  mov ecx, r8d
  shr ecx, 3
  rep movsq   # oh please no
  xor eax, eax
  test r8b, 4
  jne .L35
  test r8b, 2
  jne .L36
  # many more tail-handling cases follow
```

Basically a `rep movsq` to invoke microcode for the main copy, and then a bunch of tail-handling code to handle the odd bytes (most not show, the full assembly can be seen on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/KUsB__)).

This is an order of magnitude slower than `vmovdqu` loads/stores in my case.

And even if it was going to use `rep movs`, the CPU has ERMSB so `rep movsb` could probably do the exact number of bytes with no extra cleanup needed about as efficiently as `rep movsq`.  But the CPU does *not* have the "fast short rep" feature (Ice Lake) so we `rep movs` startup overhead is a big problem.

I'd like gcc to emit my copy loop more or less as written - at least the 32-byte AVX2 loads and store should appear as in the source.  Importantly, I want this to be local to this function: that is, not change the compiler arguments.

---

<sup>1</sup> Probably it's `memcpy` recognition followed by `memcpy` inlining.

Comment: Possibly a `volatile` unaligned_m256i could help.  (Use GNU C native vector syntax to declare your own `typedef long long vec256u __attribute__((vector_size(32), may_alias, aligned(1)))`).  It's not a good solution, but your other option to win this fight with the compiler is probably inline asm.

Comment: ICC and MSVC don't optimize intrinsics (at least not ALU intrinsics, IDK about loads/stores), but switching compilers is even more drastic.

Comment: Are you happy with the code generated by gcc-10?

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption about `memcpy` recognition appears to be correct (`__builtin_memcpy` first appears in the `ldist` pass, as can be seen in the `-fdump-tree-all` logs), and this inhibits the optimization:

```
__attribute__ ((optimize ("no-tree-loop-distribute-patterns")))
void tail_copy(char* d, const char* s, size_t overshoot) {
    copytail(d, s, overshoot);
}
```

Applying it to the template definition seems to work, too.

If the CPU supports ERMS (as most Intel CPUs with AVX2 do), it's unclear whether this is an improvement, though.

Comment: Technically ERMS only applies to `rep movsb` not `rep movsq` although `rep movsq` seems to be mostly just as fast on most recent hardware. However, "just as fast" turns out to be an order of magnitude slower in my case.

Comment: @BeeOnRope I hate `tree-loop-distribute-patterns`. Burned me on multiple occasions. The compiler should be suppressing them on any SIMD intrinsic.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this solution is too obvious, but you can prevent gcc (and clang) from recognizing  a `memcpy` in your code, by just removing the `__restrict__`:

```
template <typename T>
void copytail(T* dest, const T* src, size_t count) {
  constexpr size_t chunk_size = 4 * 32;
  size_t byte_count = sizeof(T) * count;
  size_t chunks = byte_count / chunk_size;
  auto rest = byte_count - byte_count / chunk_size * chunk_size;
  auto rest_vecs = (rest + 31) / 32;
  __m256i* dest256 = (__m256i*)((char *)dest + byte_count - rest_vecs * 32);
  __m256i* src256  = (__m256i*)((char *)src  + byte_count - rest_vecs * 32);
  for (size_t j = 0; j < rest_vecs; j++) {
      _mm256_storeu_si256(dest256 + j, _mm256_loadu_si256(src256 + j));
  }
}
```

Godbolt comparison: https://godbolt.org/z/osjO91